# how to post image to facebook events in php?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

This is my code,

```
$event_info['name'] = $name2;
$event_info['category'] = 1;
$event_info['privacy_type'] = 'OPEN';
$event_info['subcategory'] = 1;
$event_info['description'] = $description_new; //description for event
//$event_info['host'] = $desc; //description for event
//$event_info['host'] = 'You';
$event_info['location'] = $location;
$event_info['city'] = $city; //Must be a valid city name

$event_info['start_time'] = $newTime; //Converts time to UTC
$event_info['picture'] = "@http://static.eventful.com/images/small/I0-001/003/184/085-4.jpeg";
```

Everything is post except image , I want create event with event image.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines is what your looking for:

```
$fname="/tmp/foo.jpg";
$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'name' => '',
        'description' => '',
        'start_time' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'source'=> '@'.$fname
        /*...*/
);

/*Send the data*/
$result = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST', $attachment);
```

- http://forum.developers.facebook.net/profile.php?id=138142
- [Facebook graph API & PHP SDK questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439252/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-questions/3989280#3989280)