# from node.js server side: photo upload to facebook

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, serverside-javascript

According to facebook documentation, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/, to upload a photo, source type should be **"multipart/form-data"**

Now I got the image file from client to server side in node.js using 'connect-form'. and I am using 'facebook-js' module to upload the photo to facebook as,

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next){

  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files){
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('uploaded ', files.source.filename, 'to', files.source.path);

      fb.apiCall('POST', '/me/photos',
        {access_token: fields.access_token, 
             message: fields.message, 
             **source:files.source**},
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error in facebook Photo UPLOAD', error);
                return;
            }
          res.redirect('back');
        }
      );
```

The above throws an error as files.source is not encoded as "multipart/form-data"..
May I know what needs to be done here ? Do I have to put the file into memory and then use it in source ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using the current implementation of `facebook-js` (which I'm assuming is [this](https://github.com/masylum/facebook-js)). It uses the node request library which doesn't appear to have native support for sending `multipart/form-data` HTTP requests. You can implement multipart/form-data submission (see [this](http://onteria.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/multipartform-data-uploads-using-node-js-and-http-request/) for a longer example) but you'll probably need to fork the original library.

Comment: Thanks. Currently aren't there any facebook modules that can post the image to facebook ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of: all the modules appear to use `request` which doesn't have native support. Take a look at http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/1aee211ec2e8a7ff: this shows a chunk of raw node code that handles posting a photo. You might be able to adapt it for your purposes.

Comment: OK. that's a good information. What about oher services like flickr ? Is there any support for this ?

Comment: Just saw the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439252/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-questions and was wondering what 'source'=> '@'.$fname does in PHP in $fname="/tmp/foo.jpg";
$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'name' => substr(event_name),
        'description' => my_description,
        'start_time' => my_start_time,
        'link' => my_link,
        'source'=> '@'.$fname
        );

Comment: That relies on the PHP SDK's use of the PHP curl extension. The `@` syntax is used to tell curl to attach the contents. Curl handles multipart/form-data uploads just fine.