# Facebook Phot uploading PHPSDK

Tags: facebook, upload, photo

uploading photos to a wall, i can use the items below, I am using the solution on this: [Facebook graph API & PHP SDK questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439252/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-questions)

What I need to know is checking for its location once its uploaded... will that be stored in **$fb_foto** as shown in the link above...

Cheers

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example `$fb_foto` will contain the photo ID after upload, you can then access it at `/{photo id}` in the Graph API